# Can I manually decrease my FPS on windows 10?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, windows-10

I'm working on a game in Unity and I set a flag to go off and essentially kick the user if their FPS is too low. I was wondering if there was an easy way to test if it works without having to go into the bios. Or is there perhaps a way to just test it in Unity before compiling?

Comment: Did you try Unity's [Application.targetFrameRate](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-targetFrameRate.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Application.targetFrameRate`, and make sure to set vSync off.

```
void Awake () {
    QualitySettings.vSyncCount = 0;
    Application.targetFrameRate = 4;
}
```